# the application stopped when stop playing the sound

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, android-mediaplayer

I created my **Android** app to play sound when user **select option value** on i did my code well. All thing worked well but when i added my code to make user mute or stop the sound when click on **lock button** at his mobile it worked well but when i **rotate** the mobile **horizontal** the error " **the application stopped unexpectedly** " occurred. I checked my code and i reached that the error at **`onPause`** method .

```java
@Override 
protected void onResume() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);


    registerReceiver(new IntentListener(), intentFilter);

    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    super.onPause(); // Don't forget this line
    mp.pause(); // Or whatever the function is to pause it
    unregisterReceiver(new IntentListener());
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity);
}
```

```
<activity
        android:name="xx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize">
```

```
06-25 13:59:31.442: W/KeyCharacterMap(331): No keyboard for id 0
06-25 13:59:31.442: W/KeyCharacterMap(331): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-25 13:59:31.592: D/AndroidRuntime(331): Shutting down VM
06-25 13:59:31.603: W/dalvikvm(331): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.ramadan/com.ramadan.Ramadan}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3348)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at     com.ramadan.Ramadan.onPause(Ramadan.java:125)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3842)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1190)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3335)
06-25 13:59:31.672: E/AndroidRuntime(331):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: Okay, so with the logcat output we can see that at line 125 of your source file `Ramadan.java`, inside the `onPause()` method, you are trying to access an object that is null.  Could this be the line where your `mp` instance is accessed?  Indicating that the object does not exist when you are trying to access it.

Comment: i changed it to the right media player instance , but when i commented the ondestroy method the wasnot any problem but the sound still worked

Answer (score 3):

You will get lots more information if you look at the logcat output from your crash, as it will give you the reason for the exception.  However, just looking at the above code, you cannot call `registerReceiver()` and `unregisterReceiver()` with different instances, they must be the same object.  The call to `unregisterReceiver()` is likely filing with an exception saying that receiver instance was never registered before.  Your code needs to look more like this:

```
//We need a reference to this instance somehow
private IntentListener listener = new IntentListener();

@Override
public void onResume() {

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);

    registerReceiver(listener, intentFilter);

    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(listener); //must be the same instance you registered!
}
```

Comment: it solved the problem but the sound still play till i lock the mobile i used mp.release(); but the same error occurred again

Comment: Then it's time to post your logcat output, because it probably isn't the "same error", but we need to see what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to investigate the problem without logcat

However, you can skip the restart on rotate by adding config change in Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.youclassname.xxx"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: this affect on the layouts design

Comment: What is line 125 in Ramadan.java?